# Magic comment to specify root document in plain MikTeX

Tags: miktex, root

I'm aware that some LaTeX editors provide some "magic comments" to indentify the root document from within a child file `\inlude{}`-ed in the root.

Examples are the `% !TEX root = <rootfile>` comments of Atom LaTeX and Texstudio.

Since I prefer not to use a IDE, is there package or feature in MikTeX that mimics these magic comments?

Some context: I my editor (Notepad++) I can bind custom commands to shortcuts. Currently I have two of those: the first runs `latexmk main.tex` to compile the main file and I use it whenever editing the main file or its chapter subfiles. The second command runs `latexmk <current-file>` and I use it to compile TikZ source files into PDFs which I later include in my main file.

I would prefer to get rid of the first shortcut and simply run `latexmk <current-file>` on either file and have latex figure out wether to compile the file directly or redirect to the root file.

Comment: your question isn't very clear miktex is a distribution of tex-related programs but the comment syntax has to be understood by whatever you use to launch tex, either your editor or a tool such as arara , if you are simply calling tex from the commandline there isn't really anything needed as you just specify the root document to the tex command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: True, but since there already is a kind of magic comment to specify a precompiled preamble file in MikTeX pdflatex, I was wondering wether there are more..

Comment: you mean a line starting with `&`  to specify a format? Your question would be clearer if you described the interaction you have in mind. If you are just typing `pdflatex myfile` in a command window then tex will process `myfile` and there isn't really anywhere to specify anything different, or any need to do so?

Comment: I usually have a Makefile in the project root (where the root document lies) and open the editor (VIM) so it has that folder as the working directory. I start compilation with `:!make` (or a shortcut to that), so no matter which file I'm working on, the correct one is processed. But since you're using MikTeX I guess your on MS Windoof, which would require you to install some stuff to use a similar approach (namely a GNU make).